# Winning instantly at Phase 10

Tags: probability, combinatorics, solution-verification

Assuming in a deck there are $96$ cards, two of each rank from $1$ through $12$ in each of four colors, from which $10$ cards are drawn. What is the probability that there is (at least)

- two sets of three $(0.032)$
- a run of eight $(0.010)$
- a set of four and a run of four $(0.004)$

I found [this blog post](https://rockyroer.blogspot.com/2012/12/probabilities-of-phase-10-continued.html) but the described method doesn't agree with my numerical simulations above (which I double-checked). For example the first case is expressed like that:

$$\frac{\binom{12}{2} \binom{8}{3}^2 \binom{90}{4}}{\binom{96}{10}} = 0.047$$

Is this method correct? How would the other cases be calculated? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you consider wild cards etc.? In the blog, a total of 108 cards is considered (see the fourth paragraph).

Comment: No. And although the author labels his calculation "no wilds" he counts them in apparently.

Comment: He counts the wild cards in his number of possible hands, and also “doesn’t know how to handle” the fact that there are $2$ copies of each card.  So I think you should not expect exact agreement.

Answer (score 1):

Simulation is a great way to get a handle on the correct answer.  You can quickly see if what you've derived does not agree with the simulation.  For two sets of three, for instance, simulating 10,000,000 hands takes a minute or two in Python, and yields a probability of $p_1 \approx 0.0326 \pm 0.0001$.  This doesn't agree with your $0.047$, so you've done something wrong.  What you're doing wrong specifically is that you're overcounting certain hands.  For instance, hands where you have a set of strictly more than $3$ cards and another set of at least $3$ cards are counted multiple times in your enumeration.

Suppose you have exactly $m \ge 3$ cards in the smallest-rank set, and exactly $n\ge 3$ cards in the largest-rank set.  There are ${12}\choose{2}$ ways to pick the ranks, and ${8}\choose{m}$ ways to pick the cards in the first set, and ${8}\choose{n}$ ways to pick the cards in the second set; and there are then ${80}\choose{10-m-n}$ ways to pick the remaining cards (from other ranks).
This gives a count of
$$
\sum_{m=3}^{7}\sum_{n=3}^{10-m}{{12}\choose{2}}{{8}\choose{m}}{{8}\choose{n}}{{80}\choose{10-m-n}}=372250482912
$$
hands, for a probability of $0.0330$. But this is still (slightly but decidedly) inconsistent with the simulation result, because we're still overcounting hands with *three* sets of at least three cards.  Specifically, we're counting each such hand three times.  By analogous reasoning to the previous equation, there are
$$
\sum_{l=3}^{4}\sum_{m=3}^{7-l}\sum_{n=3}^{7-l-m}{{12}\choose{3}}{{8}\choose{l}}{{8}\choose{m}}{{8}\choose{n}}{{72}\choose{10-l-m-n}}=2926640640
$$
of these $3$-sets-of-at-least-$3$ hands; we need to subtract twice this number from our count.  So the desired (and now exact) probability is
$$
p_1=\frac{372250482912 - 2 \cdot 2926640640}{{96}\choose{10}}=\frac{693934094}{21363497077}\approx 0.03248223.
$$

Comment: And how would the other two probabilities be calculated?

Comment: The other two are easier (in my opinion).  For the run of 8, you have to consider the cases of a run of exactly 8, 9, or 10, and distinguish a “central” run (one not starting at 1 or ending at 12) from a non-central one in the 8 and 9 lengths.  For the last case, similarly, sum over the exact run length and set sizes, and whether the run is central, and whether the set shares a value with the run.

Comment: I say those are easier just because you don’t need to worry about an entire extra run or set.  Obviously neither is trivial.